# How do you set the order of the buttons on a toolbar?

Tags: acumatica

I'm creating a new page and the toolbar looks like so:

[image]

I want to move the Allocations button to the far right but don't see a way to set the button order. In my graph I tried putting the actions in the order I wanted, but Allocations is a lot/serial button controlled by Acumatica.

```
    public PXSave<AMClockTran> Save;
    public PXCancel<AMClockTran> Cancel;
    public PXAction<AMClockTran> clockInOut;
    public LSAMClock lsselect;
```

In the ASPX page I also tried putting the callback commands in the order I wanted.

```
        <px:PXDSCallbackCommand CommitChanges="True" Name="ClockInOut" />
        <px:PXDSCallbackCommand CommitChanges="True" Name="LSAMClock_generateLotSerial" Visible="False"/>
        <px:PXDSCallbackCommand CommitChanges="True" Name="LSAMClock_binLotSerial" Visible="True" />
```

Is there a property somewhere, or a way to move the lot/serial allocations button to another place on the toolbar?

Comment: In grid toolbar this can be achieved by the Order property but I believe the feature is lacking for the main toolbar. The order in main toolbar is a result of different side effects. Some elements like Maintenance page automatically adds the action in a hardcoded order. The Actions and Report menus have specific rules as well. Actions declared in graph should be in the same order of declaration but that won't affect the other action type that have other behavior. Currently it seems best practice is to put all Actions in the action menu because they can't be explicitly ordered.

Comment: If you decide to go that way here's some documentation:
https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2019/01/easier-way-on-adding-action-menu-in-existing-graph.html

Comment: https://www.acumatica.com/blog/adding-custom-actions-folders/

Comment: IMO lack of an explicit method to set position is problematic.

Comment: I think reordering the actions in the graph worked after all. Once I set optimizeCompilations="False" in the web.config and rebuilt the solution the button moved to the far right.

Comment: It should but I suspect there's still edge cases with built-in actions. I wasn't aware of the Actions.Move feature and upvoted the answer provided on that. For scenarios where re-ordering actions in graph doesn't produce desired effect that is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add code to the graph constructor

   Actions.Move("binLotSerial", "clockInOut");
2. **P.S.** Restart IIS to refresh cached layout

Please also note you can use the same approach for built-in actions (such as Cancel, Save, First, Prev, Next, Last, etc) as well.

For example, on the "Bills and Adjustments" screen you can put "Release" action after the "Cancel" action

```
Actions.Move("Release", "Cancel");
```

[image]

Comment: great to know about that, by any chance do you know it it work for all built in actions like the one added by maintenance page like MoveNext/Refresh/Cancel...

Comment: yes, you can use it for built-in actions as well, I've updated my answer